# Accessing playstation 3/4 data

Tags: javascript, api, sony, playstation3, playstation

Is the gaming data on playstation consoles available for anyone to use e.g through web api or wifi? I would like to display scores from a match on a live feed.

Answer (score 0):

No. Not even if you've done some serious work. Best thing you can do is actually stream the gameplay or provide screen captures. This isn't hard at all to do with a ps3 on cfw. And it is a standard feature on ps4.